NAT gateway forwarding over the same network interface
I am running a server in AWS with two ENI (NIC) attached to an instance I wish to use as a NAT server. Each ENI has its own public and private IP address (ens5 and ens6). I'd like to make it so that traffic is forwarded from the same ENI from which the traffic is received (if ens5 receives the traffic, forward via ens5; if ens6 receives the traffic, forward via ens6).
For some reason the traffic is received through ens6 and then forwarded via ens5, as shown with the following in tcpdump (client behind NAT running curl 1.1.1.1):
$ tcpdump -i any -nn host 1.1.1.1
tcpdump: data link type LINUX_SLL2
dropped privs to tcpdump
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL2 (Linux cooked v2), snapshot length 262144 bytes
08:51:16.109252 ens6  In  IP 10.255.255.26.50888 > 1.1.1.1.80: Flags [S], seq 2737496410, win 62727, options [mss 8961,sackOK,TS val 2280755138 ecr 0,nop,wscale 6], length 0
08:51:16.109267 ens5  Out IP 10.255.255.9.50888 > 1.1.1.1.80: Flags [S], seq 2737496410, win 62727, options [mss 8961,sackOK,TS val 2280755138 ecr 0,nop,wscale 6], length 0
08:51:16.110477 ens5  In  IP 1.1.1.1.80 > 10.255.255.9.50888: Flags [S.], seq 3922670560, ack 2737496411, win 65535, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 558860869 ecr 2280755138,nop,wscale 13], length 0
08:51:16.110482 ens5  Out IP 1.1.1.1.80 > 10.255.255.26.50888: Flags [S.], seq 3922670560, ack 2737496411, win 65535, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 558860869 ecr 2280755138,nop,wscale 13], length 0
[...]

Configuration:
$ sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

$ iptables -t nat -L -n -v
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  138  9556 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      ens5    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    1   358 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      ens6    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

$ iptables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

$ ip route
default via 10.255.255.1 dev ens5 proto dhcp src 10.255.255.9 metric 512 
default via 10.255.255.1 dev ens6 proto dhcp src 10.255.255.14 metric 522 
10.255.255.0/28 dev ens5 proto kernel scope link src 10.255.255.9 metric 512 
10.255.255.0/28 dev ens6 proto kernel scope link src 10.255.255.14 metric 522 
10.255.255.1 dev ens5 proto dhcp scope link src 10.255.255.9 metric 512 
10.255.255.1 dev ens6 proto dhcp scope link src 10.255.255.14 metric 522 
10.255.255.2 dev ens5 proto dhcp scope link src 10.255.255.9 metric 512 
10.255.255.2 dev ens6 proto dhcp scope link src 10.255.255.14 metric 522 

$ ip rule
0:  from all lookup local
10001:  from 10.255.255.14 lookup 10001 proto static
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

$ ip route show table 10001
default via 10.255.255.1 dev ens6 proto dhcp metric 522 
10.255.255.0/28 dev ens6 proto static scope link

How can I ensure traffic received by ensX is forwarded by ensX?

For now it doesn't work because the ip rule does not match (the source is not the interface ip address but the source host address), then the main route table is used and have a higher priority for ens5.
This is because the routing decision is before the masquerade (in postrouting):

You should create 2 dedicated route tables:
cat << EOF >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables 
2 ifaceA
3 ifaceB
EOF

Then fill them with only one interface routes informations:
ip route add default via 10.255.255.1 dev ens5 proto static src 10.255.255.9 table ifaceA
ip route add 10.255.255.0/28 dev ens5 proto kernel scope link src 10.255.255.9 table ifaceA
ip route add default via 10.255.255.1 dev ens6 proto static src 10.255.255.14 table ifaceB
ip route add 10.255.255.0/28 dev ens6 proto kernel scope link src 10.255.255.14 table ifaceB

And create rules based on the interface:
ip rule add iif ens5 lookup ifaceA
ip rule add iif ens6 lookup ifaceB

